# Can't find equivalent RadControl *.dll files in latest RadControl release

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik, upgrade, rad-controls

I'm upgrading a very old version of RadControl *.dll files--not sure what version these *.dll files are from.  Were all of these *.dll files (listed below) combined into a single *.dll file in the latest Telerik RadControl version?  Perhaps in one of these files?  Also, what is the XML file used for.  Should it be placed in the same folder as the *.dll file with the same name?

```
C:\Program Files\Telerik\RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Q2 2011\Bin35\Telerik.Web.Design.dll

C:\Program Files\Telerik\RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Q2 2011\Bin35\Telerik.Web.UI.dll

C:\Program Files\Telerik\RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Q2 2011\Bin35\Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.dll

C:\Program Files\Telerik\RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Q2 2011\Bin35\Telerik.Web.UI.XML
```

**Old Telerik RadControl files:**

```
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadAjax.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadCalendar.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadComboBox.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadEditor.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadGrid.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadInput.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadMenu.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadSpell.NET2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadSplitter.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadTabStrip.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadToolbar.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadTreeView.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadUpload.Net2.dll
C:\source\clients\web\framework\_base\docs\admin\references\Telerik\RadWindow.Net2.dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Telerik.Web.UI.dll now contains all of Telerik's controls in a single DLL.  The old files you mention (that end in '.Net2.dll') are actually for an old edition of the controls called the RadControls for ASP.NET - which included each control in it's own DLL.  Now, it's RadControls for ASP.NET **AJAX** and everything is in the one DLL.

The XML files are optional and provide extra information to things like IntelliSense in Visual Studio.  Instead of just getting basic IntelliSense, the XML file allows you to have comments from Telerik shown.  You'll want to place the XML files in the same folder as the DLL.  See here for more information: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-intellisense-vs2010.html